# How to read a proto3 custom option from Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-java, proto3

Given the following service:

```
message Message {
  string content = 1;
}

service EchoService {
  rpc echo (Message) returns (Message) {
    option (google.api.http) = { get: "/echo" };
  }
}
```

I want to read the option from Java. My understand is the following code should work:

```
HttpRule rule = Message.getDescriptor()
  .getOptions()
  .getExtension(AnnotationsProto.http)
```

However this doesn't compile, complaining about typing issues where it cannot resolve the method.

I am trying to follow this: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto.html#customoptions

So the question is, how do I read the option from Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing, its actually a completely different type.

`AnnotationsProto.http` implements type with a generic of `MethodOptions` (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DescriptorProtos.MethodOptions.html)

Whereas `Message.getDescriptor().getOptions().getExtensions()` is expecting a parameter with a generic of `MessageOptions` (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DescriptorProtos.MessageOptions.html)

**Method**Options vs **Message**Options - perhaps I need to get down to specsavers...

Comment: Maybe also add how you finally managed to access the `MethodOptions` 

Answer (score 0):

The following groovy code will fetch the http annotation

```
import com.google.api.AnnotationsProto

        def methodDescriptorSupplier = (ProtoMethodDescriptorSupplier) grpcMethodDescriptor.getSchemaDescriptor()
        def extension = methodDescriptorSupplier.getMethodDescriptor().getOptions().getExtension(AnnotationsProto.http)
```